# Wrapping a link tag around a list item

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering what the best way is to navigate the user to a users profile page when he clicks a `<li>` item on the members page.

```
<li>
    <img src="images/pic.png" alt="John Smiths's Profile Picture" class="profile-pic">
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="skills">PHP, ASP, MySQL, SQL Server, Javascript</div>
</li>
```

That's the sort of markup for each list item, and it comes out at about `640x50` block width/height. I want the user to go to their profile page when they click on any part of the `<li>` element.

I tried wrapping the entire list item in a link element (`<a>`), but that just results in a `0x0` sized link element. I'd also prefer not to use Javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" title="Link text" class="list-link"> 
      <img src="images/pic.png" alt="John Smiths's Profile Picture" class="profile-pic">
      <span class="name">John Smith</span>
      <span class="skills">PHP, ASP, MySQL, SQL Server, Javascript</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

css:

```
.list-link{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that aswell, but it didn't let me click *any* part of the li element, only the image and the the spans. Plus, according to another comment it's invalid HTML.

Comment: I used spans instead of divs, that is valid.

I just added some css that will make the whole li clickable

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `A` around `LI` is invalid HTML. Why not just wrap the entire content of the innerHTML of the LI in an A-tag instead?

```
<li>
    <a href="...">
    <img src="images/pic.png" alt="John Smiths's Profile Picture" class="profile-pic">
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="skills">PHP, ASP, MySQL, SQL Server, Javascript</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: A div in an a-element is not allowed